# Internal storage JS files not linked with android webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have stored index.html file in internal storage and the html file uses the below code to add a script in order to display on webview:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://url.net/4.2/something.js"></script>
```

which works fine but when I try to link JS files from internal storage instead of the link, I get nothing in webview.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="something.js"></script>
```

The above didn't work. Can someone tell me how to link with files in internal storage? I also tried `/sdcard/something.js` which also didn't work.

The JS folder and index.html file are in the root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store your js file to app internal storage then use this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///data/data/***com.yourproject.example***/files/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

and change your package name accordingly.

The best way is to create script tag dynamically rather than creating hardcode. So that you can find absolute path with the help of android api and then pass path to javascript method .
For example

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:loadPage('" + Yourfile path +
                        "');");
```

and JS method is

```
function loadPage(path){
    var articleTextScript = document.createElement('script');
    articleTextScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    articleTextScript.src = path;
    articleTextScript.id = 'articleTextScript';
    var header = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    header.appendChild(articleTextScript);
}
```

Comment: js file is in root directory as the index.html file is so the first code should be changed to what?

Comment: My JS method is not simple  and I tried the hardcoded method as well but it didn't work.

Comment: please provide some code snippet that you used so that i will check the exact issue

Comment: I used file:///data/files/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js as my file is in root. Also checked with your code but both didn't work

Comment: I know your code and my JS file can work with modification as when I tested with assets folder it does work fine. But I will mark your answer correct as soon as I find the internal storage one also working.

Comment: I wish I could but I don't have reputation of 15. I am new here

Answer (score 0):

Is the js file store at location relative to your index.html? You can use

```
@Override
public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String resUrl) {
    super.onLoadResource(view, resUrl);
    // LOG resURL
}
```

Another trick that I found to use shouldInterceptRequest to go load the js yourself

```
        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String resUrl) {
            if (resUrl.startsWith("somepattern")) {
                // Figure out where the file is
                // Load it into a stream
                WebResourceResponse response = new WebResourceResponse("text/javascript", "utf-8", /*Input stream*/);
                    return response;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Should I substitute Inputstream with new FileInputStream(new File("/sdcard/js/...")) or something else? And what should I enter in "somepattern"?

Comment: well I'm assuming that a mix of your resources will be from local/web. If all of your resources are local then you can just skip the check and intercept everything. Yes you can use any type of InputStream. But do try onLoadResource first though to see if it is an easy pathing fix.